# Go - Cross compiling with CGO using xgo library

Tags: macos, go, docker, cgo, gokogiri

I'm trying to compile a GO application, which uses the [gokiri](https://github.com/moovweb/gokogiri) library.
I installed docker and compiled locally the [xgo](https://github.com/karalabe/xgo) cross compiler for go.
When trying to execute the following command:

```
./xgo mydomain.com/test/test-app
```

I get the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/parser.h:810:0,
             from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/globals.h:18,
             from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/threads.h:35,
             from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlmemory.h:218,
             from /usr/include/libxml2/libxml/tree.h:1307,
             from ../../github.com/moovweb/gokogiri/help/help.go:6:
/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/encoding.h:28:19: fatal error: iconv.h: No such file or directory
```

I've installed `xcode-tools` which helped me compile it for my machine (mac ox El Capitan). BUT, I cannot get it compiled to other environment.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

**Update 1:**

I've tried to add the dependency, but got the same result:

```
./xgo --deps /usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/ mydomain.com/test/test-app
```

It was even mentioned in the logs of the `xgo` that this library was already cached:

```
Dependency already cached: /Users/macuser/.xgo-cache/1.14.
```

Comment: It looks you need to provide `xgo` with all the C dependencies via the `--deps` flag. The build container somehow needs to know where to get the deps for the C packages it's building.

Comment: @JimB Check my edited question, it didn't helped.

Comment: I would try to build it in a linux container without xgo, both to see exactly what's not working, and because it's probably easier and will give you more control to use docker directly than to solve this with xgo.

Comment: @JimB Can you give me some reference on how to build it in a linux container using docker? I'm pretty new at it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Once you can run a container, building the package inside the container is the same as on a full Linux host. [Get Started With Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/getstarted/) is probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation:

> It is assumed that the dependent C/C++ library is configure/make
>   based, was properly prepared for cross compilation and is available as
>   a tarball download (.tar, .tar.gz or .tar.bz2). Further plans include
>   extending this to cmake based projects, if need arises (please open an
>   issue if it's important to you).
>
> Such dependencies can be added via the --deps argument. They will be
>   retrieved prior to starting the cross compilation and the packages
>   cached to save bandwidth on subsequent calls.

So in this example, it would be:

`./xgo --deps https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv/libiconv-1.15.tar.gz mydomain.com/test/test-app`